# CKEditor 4.5.2 - allowedContent for <figcaption> without widget plugin

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, figure

Is there a way to add `allowedContent` to specific `<figcaption>` without using `widget` plugin ? For example I want to allow `br em strong sub sup u s; a[!href]` for `<figcaption>`.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?. I have exactly the same problem